# Threejs r73 shadow changes -- how to control shadow camera frustum?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I ran into an issue while updating from r72 to r73. I think it has something to do with the shadow changes in r73. I also tried running the latest in master, but the issues persist.

I created two fiddles to illustrate the problem. This fiddle is using r72 http://jsfiddle.net/01xm6taz/3/ this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mtcq070x/2/ is using r73

The issue is that I have lost control over the shadowCamera's frustum and I can't seem to figure out how to toggle shadows correctly in r73. It is important to be able to control the frustum in order to get decent shadows with a low resolution shadow map and toggling shadows is also essential. If I can control the frustum again then I can toggle differently (by setting far and near to 0 or something)

If you open the r72 fiddle, you'll see that you can control the frustum in r72 but not r73.

Specifically, the following lines no longer work in r73:

```
        light.shadowCamera.near = self.shadownear;
        light.shadowCamera.far = self.shadowfar;
        light.shadowCamera.left = -self.shadowleft;
        light.shadowCamera.right = self.shadowright;
        light.shadowCamera.bottom = -self.shadowtop;
        light.shadowCamera.top = self.shadowbottom;
        light.shadowCamera.shadowBias = self.shadowbias;
        light.shadowDarkness = self.shadowdarkness;
        light.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

I could stick to r72, but then I will lose out on some of the nice .toJSON updates we got in r73.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the API was just changed slightly. The following code works fine:

```
    light.shadow.camera.near = self.shadownear;
    light.shadow.camera.far = self.shadowfar;
    light.shadow.camera.left = -self.shadowleft;
    light.shadow.camera.right = self.shadowright;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -self.shadowtop;
    light.shadow.camera.top = self.shadowbottom;
    light.shadow.camera.shadowBias = self.shadowbias;
    light.shadowDarkness = self.shadowdarkness;
    light.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

I wish that breaking changes were outlined a little more clearly :)

Comment: also  i believe its  shadow.bias and now shadow.darkness is gone